# Flutter Navigator.popUntil() with ModalRoute.withName() not working in profile and release mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, release-mode

I have a function that navigates to a new page with route settings

```
void pushWithSettings(
    {@required BuildContext context, @required Widget newPage}) {
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: RouteSettings(
            name: newPage.toString(),
          ),
          builder: (_) => newPage));
}
```

and I pop till a particular page using

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(Page().toString));
```

This works well in debug mode but in profile and release mode it pops only once

An Example for context

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/main.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(child: Text("First Page"),),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){
            pushWithSettings(context: context, newPage: SecondPage());
          },
          child: Text("Navigate to second", style: TextStyle(inherit: false)),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(child: Text("Second Page"),),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          pushWithSettings(context: context, newPage: ThirdPage());
        },
        child: Text("Navigate to third", style: TextStyle(inherit: false)),
      )
    ],
  );
}
}

class ThirdPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(child: Text("Third Page"),),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(FirstPage().toString()));
          },
          child: Text("Navigate to first", style: TextStyle(inherit: false),),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In debug mode tapping the button in the third page navigates to the first page but in profile and release mode tapping the button does nothing.
I'm currently running flutter 1.17.4 on the stable channel

Comment: Maybe Page().toString() is not returning the same in debug and release. Could you try to add another String as the routeName? Try with a simple string to see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code an `FirstPage().toString()` in Profile mode returns 'Widget' while it returns 'FirstPage' in debug.

I would add a mixin that contains a routeName string you can use.

Also remember, that at least for web is recommended that your initial route is with '/'.

```dart
void pushWithSettings(
    {@required BuildContext context, @required NamedRoute newPage}) {
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: RouteSettings(
            name: newPage.routeName,
          ),
          builder: (_) => newPage));
}

mixin NamedRoute implements Widget {
  String get routeName;
}


class ThirdPage extends StatelessWidget with NamedRoute {
  @override
  String get routeName => '/third_page';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text("Third Page"),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(FirstPage().routeName));
          },
          child: Text(
            "Navigate to first",
            style: TextStyle(inherit: false),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Check the codepen https://codepen.io/jamesblasco/pen/QWyBQOm

Comment: I tried the mixin. Still didn't work. You're right about the name changing to Widget. I can't run dev tools with profile mode for some reason.

Comment: The mixin worked. I made a mistake while implementing. Thank you.
I tried using runtimeType and it worked also so
name: newPage.routeName became name: newPage.runtimeType

Comment: Glad you make it work. Just notice that flutter recommends to use a path-like naming for your routes

Comment: "Mobile apps often manage a large number of routes and it's often easiest to refer to them by name. Route names, by convention, use a path-like structure (for example, '/a/b/c'). The app's home page route is named '/' by default. "https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html

Answer (score 2):

The first answer works but to avoid adding mixins to all pages I have available I used `runtimeType` instead so

```
settings: RouteSettings(
            name: newPage.toString(),
          ),
```

became

```
settings: RouteSettings(
            name: newPage.runtimeType.toString(),
          ),
```