# Unable to read passed RouteSettings inside popUntil routes - Issue only in Release/Profile

Tags: flutter, navigation

This looks possible duplicate of

[Flutter Navigator.popUntil() with ModalRoute.withName() not working in profile and release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62855976/flutter-navigator-popuntil-with-modalroute-withname-not-working-in-profile-a)

But it's not.

The above question resolves the issue of mismatched route names, But in my case, RouteSettings is always null.

**Issue only for Android and only for Release/Profile builds**

```
// Pushing the route
Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
             return ScreenA();
        },
        settings: RouteSettings(name: "screenA"),
    ),
);


// Popping until pushed route
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) {
    print(route.settings.name);
    // Here name and arguments are always null
    return route.settings.name == 'screenA';
});
```

**UPDATE**

Also tried with `pushNamed` with specified routes, and `onGenerateRoute` method. `RouteSettings.name` and `RouteSettings.arguments` is always null.

**Flutter 1.22.5**

Comment: so do you mean that [ModalRoute.withName](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/withName.html) does not work too?

Comment: Yes right, I basically have similar implementation of `withName` method.  Both doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried the above snippet and all works fine, even without specifying routes it works. I definitely am doing something wrong in my project. But I have no idea at all :). Thanks for your time.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: Can this be an issue of context? I somewhere use context from the global key.

Comment: i dont know, tried to setup a breakpoint inside `popUntil` and see whats happening there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling `popUntil` from inside a dialog. Like below example,

```
await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Dialog(
      child: Container(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) {
              return route.settings.name == 'screenA';
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

And the issue was because of `await`, Removing it works perfectly fine. If using await before `showDialog` `RouteSettings.name` comes `null`.